# React state not being updated as expected using functional call to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following method

```
handlePlayerSaveToggle(playerId) {
    this.setState(state => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
        state.players[playerId].saved = !state.players[playerId].saved;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
        return state;
    });
}
```

It is a callback method which is called on the press of a save button. I have been having issues lately with unexpected results when using the functional flavour of setState.

In this situation, the second call to console.log prints out a different object to the first call (the saved parameter is correctly updated - screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of console log output]

Now the issue comes with the updated state. I have another console log as a first line of the render method (also pictured in the screenshot - line 58). As you can see, the saved parameter has *not* been updated to true.

Now what really bothers me is if I switch to the non-functional flavour, everything works as expected.

```
handlePlayerSaveToggle(playerId) {
    let players = this.state.players;
    players[playerId].saved = !players[playerId].saved;
    this.setState({
        players: players
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your full component code?

Comment: I think this is enough, given I've posted a working alternative. My question is why I cannot achieve the same behaviour as the second snippet when I use the functional flavour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the bind:     this.handlePlayerSaveToggle =this.handlePlayerSaveToggle.bind(this);

Working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-leaf-w84pl?file=/src/App.js:256-330

Comment: if he had forgotten to bind its function, he would actually face an error instead of an incorrect state update.

Comment: exactly. As I said, the second snippet works as expected. The issue is with the first, I don't understand why the functional style doesn't achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an object state, you should assign as new object. Because object is assigned as reference type.

```js
handlePlayerSaveToggle(playerId) {
    let players = this.state.players;
    players[playerId].saved = !players[playerId].saved;
    this.setState({
        players: [...players]
    });
}
```

Comment: the second snippet already works as expected, the object assignment is not necessary. The first snipper is the issue.